# how to return different values from a mocked method in Jmockit?

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

I have a situation where I need to unit test an EJB method. Target EJB has dependency on another EJB like ,

```
@Stateless(name = "service1")
@Interceptors({FaultBarrierInterceptor.class})
public class Service1 implements Service1Remote {
 @EJB(beanName = "service2")
 private Service2Local service2;
}
```

Service2Local is local EJB interface and has a method that I mock as below in @Before method of Junit,

```
new MockUp<Service2Local>(){
            @Mock
            public void $init() {
            }
            @Mock
            public List<String> search(){
                return List_1;
            }
}.getMockInstance();
```

Is it possible to get different lists ( from mocked search() method ) in different test methods ( e.g List_2 ) ? I wish this search() method to return different values in different @Test methods.

I tried a new MockUp in my test method but that didn't work. 
In Mockito, I can achieve this by calling when().thenReturn() in my test method on dependency mocked object.

I am using @Injectable to inject dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, There are two possible ways I can think of.

1. Wrap your mocking code in a method and call it from different
   methods

```
public void setUpMocksForService2(final List<String>
    stringList) {
        new MockUp<Service2Local>(){
            @Mock
            public void $init() {
            }
            @Mock
            public List<String> search(){
                return stringList;
            }
        }.getMockInstance();
```

} and call this from your different test methods. Disadvantage here is that everytime a new mock up will be created.

2. Call the above method once @BeforeClass and make the list of strings a member of test class, modify this list accordingly in each test case.

Off topic Note: You can also use expectations to mimic behaviour of when and then of mockito

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not very familiar with Expectations API , I will try that . Expectations seem more suitable. I tried approach#1 and its not working since Mocks specified in any general method are not working. I guess, mocks need to be specified only in Before method and At_Before methods can't take any parameters so I can't pass on the list.